# Global Variables vs Direct Conection to pass data between view controllers ios

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I don't think the title uses the right terminology so I'll try to clarify now.

I have two view controllers which i want to pass data between. view 1 has a tableView and the 2nd view has a MKMapView. Now in the corresponding controllers I want when you click on a cell in view 1 it sends you to the place on the map which the cell indicates eg. a New York cell would send to a map of new York. So I tried in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` that I create an instance of the second controller which would transfer the data to it. But when I did that it would always return a nil value in the second view controller.

So instead I created a 3rd swift file which has some global variables and when I transfer the data via them it works perfectly. Why is this so?

Cheers.

EDIT: Before the I went via a third file

Code for the ViewController 1

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    var selectedCell = array[indexPath.row]

    var viewController2 = ViewController2()

    viewController2.textLabel1 = selectedCell.name
    coord.textLabel2 = selectedCell.coordinate
}
```

Code for ViewController 2

```
@IBOutlet weak var textLabel1: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var textLabel2: UILabel!
```

Code for View Controller 2 going via 3rd file

```
@IBOutlet weak var textLabel1: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var textLabel2: UILabel!
override func viewDidLoad() {
textLabel1.text = globalVar1
textLabel2.text = globalVar2

}
```

Code from the 3rd File

```
var globalVar1: String!
var globalVar2: String!
```

So from the comments below I take it that in the first way the textLabels hadn't been initialised yet, so the values I assigned to them where turned into nil values. Is this correct? If so how would you do the first way correctly

Comment: How you are instantiating view controllers.Post code it will help.

Comment: How are you transitioning to the second view controller?  Via a segue?

Comment: Yeah just a normal modal view made via storyboard @Paulw11

Comment: Then your problem is that you are instantiating a new view controller in your code. You should implement `prepareForSegue` and set the property on the destination view controller there

Comment: `override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
       
        var 2ndViewController = ViewController2()
        
        2ndViewController.var1 = tempvar1
        2ndViewController.var1 = tempvar2
        
        performSegueWithIdentifier("trans", sender: self) //crashing on this line
        
        
        
    }`

Comment: is this what you were thinking? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I had to guess, and I would because I cannot comment for more info yet(i get in trouble ).

It's because you are trying to assign it to an outlet.
The outlet has not been set yet which means when it is set (I think around ViewDidLoad)
the outlet will be set to nil.
The properties should however be retained if the object hasn't gone out of the heap that is.

Comment: No problem. :) So from that code, does your answer still stand? If so how would I do the first way, and get it to work? Thanks again!

Comment: I just saw you posted some code. unfortunately I haven't studied swift yet. but, I think that you need 2 more properties with a strong pointer that you can assign after you instantiate from VC1 I'm not sure about using the globals maybe I'm wrong though. again I really haven't looked at swift at all.

Answer (score -1):

PSedu code:

first view :
Your table view

Second View:
your map view

How to work

In you second view:
Add a NSMutableArray *valueArraytoGet in .h file,set its property 
@synchronize it in .m file

Now in your first view at didSelectRowAtIndex method

create object of Second View Controller 
and assign data as
SecondViewController *object=......
object.valueArraytoGet=[assign ur value array here]....

Hope it will help